# letters and envelopes randomly sent to companies

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> After having written n job application letters and addressing the n
> corresponding envelopes, your child does you the kind favor of
> inserting one letter into each of the envelopes and mailing them.
> However, she thought all the letters were the same, so that they were
> placed into the envelopes in a completely random fashion.
>
> **(a)** What is the probability that all companies get the correct letter?

> **(b)** What is the probability that exactly k are correct?

> **(c)** What is the probability that at least one is correct?

My solution attempt for **(a)**:

The probability that the first company gets the wrong letter is $1/n$.

Let's do it for n companies:

$\frac{1}{n}*\frac{1}{n-1}*\frac{1}{n-2}*...*\frac{1}{n-k}..* \frac{1}{1}$

Where the last fraction is one because the last company surely will get the correct letter conditioning on the fact that the n-1 companies before got the correct letter.

Hence, my solution for (a) would be:

$\frac{1}{n!}$

Is this correct?

**(c)**:
This would be equivalent to one minus the complement (that no letter is correct).
Again we would have

$\frac{n-1}{n}*\frac{n-2}{n-1}...*\frac{n-(n-1)}{n-(n-2)}*\frac{0}{1}=0$

and $1-0=1$

**b)**:
Here there are n! possible orderings.
This means that the first letter could be false, the following k letters correct and the remaining n-k-1 letters false again.
Or it could be that the first letters are false, the following k letters correct and the remaining n-k-2 letters false again.
And so on (hence n!)

Is my reasoning correct in this case ?
What would your solution be for b)?
What about a) and b). Are my solutions correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for **(a)** is okay.

More directly you can state that there are $n!$ possible arrangements/permutations/outcomes and in exactly one of them we deal with the case described under **(a)**. Then - because the outcomes are equiprobable - we can apply the rule that: $$\text{probability }=\text{ number of favourable outcomes divided by number of possible outcomes}$$

For handling **(b)** in a similar way you should be familiar with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). Here the number of favourable outcomes equals: $$\binom{n}{k}\times!(n-k)=\frac{n!}{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
First we make a selection of $k$ out of $n$. They represent the letters with a correct adress. The remaining $n-k$ letters have a wrong adress and there are $!(n-k)$ derangements on $n-k$ objects. Further the number of possible outcomes is again $n!$ so applying the rule we find probability:$$\frac1{k!}\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

Based on this we find easily for **(c)** the probability:$$1-\frac{!n}{n!}=1-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i!}$$If $n$ is not small then you can also approximate on base of: $$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\approx e^{-1}$$